# Pass piece of State to React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a simple weather app built using React. The `App.js` code includes the following in its `return()` statement:

```
<Routes>
  <Route exact path="/" element={<Form />} />
  <Route exact path="/weather/*" element={<Weather />} />
</Routes>
```

`Form.jsx` takes in user input, sets as State, and looks like:

```
export default function Form() {
  const [zipCode, setZipCode] = useState('');
  const getZip = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setZipCode(e.target[0].value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={getZip}>
        <input id="zip" />
    <label htmlFor="zip">Your Zip Code</label>
        <Link to="/Weather" role="button" type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Enter</Link>
      </form>
  )}
```

`Weather.jsx` is supposed to take that zip code and make an API call to get weather data:

```
function Weather() {
  const { zipCode } = useParams();
  const [forecastObj, setForecastObj] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://apiservice.com/forecast/loc=${zipCode}`)
}
```

The app is supposed to display `Form.jsx`, and switch to `Weather.jsx` once the zip code is submitted. When I input a zip code I get an error: `GET https://apiservice.com/forecast/loc=undefined 400`, so the zip code isn't being passed to `Weather.jsx`. Most of the resources I've found through googling seem to be for older versions (lots of `this.state = state` or similar). Other resources say to use `useParams`, which I have set up in `Weather.jsx`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your two components are not related. You'll need some way to share state between them. One built-in option is the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). Another would be a redux store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you setup your `weather` [`Route`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/route) path to accept a parameter of `zipCode`, you can imperatively navigate there (instead of using [`Link`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/link)) with the value captured in your `Form` component.

Then in your `Weather` component, you can access the route params with [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-params).

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  useParams,
  useNavigate
} from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Form />} />
        <Route exact path="/weather/:zipCode" element={<Weather />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Form() {
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  const [zipCode, setZipCode] = useState("");

  const onSubmit = () => {
    navigate(`/weather/${zipCode}`);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <label>
        Your Zip Code{" "}
        <input onChange={(e) => setZipCode(e.target.value)} />
      </label>
      <button>submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}

function Weather() {
  const { zipCode } = useParams();

  return `Weather for ${zipCode}`;
}
```

[image: Edit blissful-snowflake-jklbxb]

Comment: Isn't the navigation object also present as props in react router?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of @JoelHager

Answer (score 0):

```
<Link to="/Weather" role="button" type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Enter</Link>
```

Your `Link` does not pass any params to `Weather.jsx` and `zipCode` is also not static, so you cannot get any param data in `Weather`.

If you want to have params in `Weather.jsx`, you could replace `Link` with a primitive button element, and add `useHistory` - React Router v5 (or `useNavigate` - React Router v6) for the navigation instead.

React Router v5

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Form() {
  const [zipCode, setZipCode] = useState('');
  const history = useHistory();
  const getZip = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setZipCode(e.target[0].value);
    history.push(`/weather?zipCode=${e.target[0].value}`)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={getZip}>
        <input id="zip" />
    <label htmlFor="zip">Your Zip Code</label>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Enter</button>
      </form>
  )}
```

React Router v6

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Form() {
  const [zipCode, setZipCode] = useState('');
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const getZip = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setZipCode(e.target[0].value);
    navigate(`/weather?zipCode=${e.target[0].value}`);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={getZip}>
        <input id="zip" />
    <label htmlFor="zip">Your Zip Code</label>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Enter</button>
      </form>
  )}
```

If you want to have `zipCode` as a part of the URL implicitly, you can modify `Route` like below

```
<Routes>
  <Route exact path="/" element={<Form />} />
  <Route exact path="/weather/:zipCode" element={<Weather />} />
</Routes>
```

And modify `Form` accordingly

React Router v5

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Form() {
  const [zipCode, setZipCode] = useState('');
  const history = useHistory();
  const getZip = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setZipCode(e.target[0].value);
    history.push(`/weather/${e.target[0].value}`)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={getZip}>
        <input id="zip" />
    <label htmlFor="zip">Your Zip Code</label>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Enter</button>
      </form>
  )}
```

React Router v6

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Form() {
  const [zipCode, setZipCode] = useState('');
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const getZip = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setZipCode(e.target[0].value);
    navigate(`/weather/${e.target[0].value}`)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={getZip}>
        <input id="zip" />
    <label htmlFor="zip">Your Zip Code</label>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Enter</button>
      </form>
  )}
```

Comment: OP is using `react-router-dom@6`, so the `useHistory` hook should be the `useNavigate` hook. 

Answer (score 0):

To use `router params` you need to properly name them when you declare the `Route path`:

```
 <Route exact path="/weather/:zipCode" element={<Weather />} />
```

And then navigate to the proper route:

```
<Link to={`/weather/${zipCode}`} role="button" type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Enter</Link>
```

Now you should be able to access the `params` properly when on the `/weather/` route:

```
  const { zipCode } = useParams();
```